# Passing the selected category from the Navigation bar to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a side bar for category of products.
My `controller` is this:

```
public PartialViewResult Menu(string cateogry = null)
{
    ViewBag.SelectedCategory = cateogry;

    IEnumerable<string> cateogries = repository.Products.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);

    return PartialView(cateogries);
}
```

And my routing is this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(null,
        "",
        new
        {
            controller = "Product",
            action = "List",
            category = (string)null,
            page = 1
        }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(null,
        "Page{page}",
        new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category = (string)null },
        new { page = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(null,
        "{category}",
        new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(null,
        "{category}/Page{page}",
        new { controller = "Product", action = "List" },
        new { page = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
}
```

But still category is passed as `null` when I click on my category buttons so it doesn't highlight the selected category button.  What else am I missing?

And the `view`:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product", null, new {@class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"})

@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(link, new
    {
        controller = "Product",
        action = "List",
        category = link,
        page = 1
    },
        new
        {
            @class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" +
            (link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "btn-primary" : "")
        })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant portion of your view? You are setting the `category` parameter default to `null`, you must not be binding the category selection properly and therefore your controller is getting the default value (or something like this).

Comment: @wahwahwah updated with the view portion.

Comment: Your link shows a List action, but in your code you've shown one called Menu.  Also, category is spelled differently in your routes and view compared to the controller action.

Comment: Thanks, spelling of "category" was the original issue...also one white space missing when I was attaching "btn-primary" CSS class.